# How to Make Global Viewcontroller that runs in background?

Tags: objective-c, delegates, dropbox, global

I am making an app that use Core Dropbox SDK and make sync of all file and folders from document directory. Now I want to make that thing global so any one can integrate that in their app but problem is when I call method of global Viewcontroller it run that method but didn't run Dropbox delegate method so how can make that work.

```
///This is method that i am calling from another viewcontroller    
-(void)startsync{

   self.restClient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
self.restClient.delegate = self;
[self.restClient loadMetadata:@"/"];
}
```

but this doesn't work dropbox delegate method when I call this method from another viewcontroller

```
/// call this method from another viewcontroller
ListVC *list = [[ListVC alloc]init];
[list startsync];
```

Answer (score 1):

Put below method in AppDelegate.h

```
-(void)startsync;
```

now AppDelegate.m,

```
-(void)startsync{

  self.restClient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
  self.restClient.delegate = self;
  [self.restClient loadMetadata:@"/"];
 }
```

Now create AppDelegate instance in yourviewcontroller.m

```
- (void)yourmethod{

AppDelegate *delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

[delegate startsync];
}
```

Call Method

```
[self yourmethod];
```

Comment: This will not work because i have some delegate method of Dropbox SDK in myviewcontroller.m that didnt call

Comment: DropBox Dlegate method move to AppDelegate.h, also import DropBox Framework in AppDelegate.h